# How to display only value that occurs second highest number of times?

Tags: mysql

Write a query to display the customer name who visited the second highest number of times

```
select customer_id,count(*)  from booking group by customer_id ;
```

using this query i got the count of number of visits for each customer as shown below

```
CUSTOMER_ID,COUNT(*)
C001,6
C002,1
C003,1
C004,1
C005,4
```

but i want to display only c005 since he has visited the second maximum time

Comment: Anything you tried already and want to show?

Comment: Are you showing us an actual table or the output of a query on some table?

Comment: What about duplicates, e.g. if two `customer_id` had a count of 4?

Comment: it should display both ordered by the customer id in asc order @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT customer_id, COUNT(*)
FROM booking
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING COUNT(*) <> (SELECT MAX(t.custCount)
                    FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS custCount
                          FROM booking
                          GROUP BY customer_id) t )
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

As a side note, this won't work if there are ties for second place.  In this case, you use the above query as a condition in the `WHERE` clause, e.g.

```
SELECT customer_id
FROM booking
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = (query given above)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a outer query and filter the same like

```
select customer_id from (
select customer_id,
count(*) as datacount
from booking 
group by customer_id ) xxx
order by datacount desc
limit 1;
```